# Getting SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF intents from a widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget and I would like to check if the screen is off or on.

I can't use PowerMananger.isScreenOn because I want to support Android 1.5/1.6 .

So I tried to register SCREEN_ON/SCREEN_OFF actions in the manifest but that doesn't work. Seems like only registerReceiver works for those intents. ([Android - how to receive broadcast intents ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1588267/383414))

The question is, where should I register my widget?

I can't register the screen intents receiver from my widget because you can't call registerReceiver from another BroadcastReceiver that is stated in the manifest.

I thought about calling it in the onCreate of my configuration activity.

The problem is that I don't call unregisterReceiver, so I get an exception for a leak.

Is there any other solution to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to start a service in the `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method in the AppwidgetProvider subclass. Like:

```
        if (intent.getAction().equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_ENABLED)) {
        Intent listenerService=new Intent(context,ScreenMoniterService.class);
        startService(listenerService);
        return;
    }
```

Then in the `public void onCreate()` method of this service, register the BroadcastReceiver and in the `public void onDestroy()` method, unregister it.
Of course, you should stop that service when all of the appwidget are deleted.

```
        if (intent.getAction().equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DISABLED)) {

        Intent listenerService=new Intent(context,ScreenMoniterService.class);
        stopService(listenerService);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: so the service has to run as long as the widget is running?

Comment: Yes. This is what I am doing with my appwidget. Because the AppWidgetProvider is essentially a BroadcastReceiver, the widget itself is just running within the onReceive() method, so I thinks it had better to start a service. Please see the accepted answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481625/android-widget-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

registerReceiver:

`final IntentFilter bcFilter = new IntentFilter();
 bcFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON); 
 bcFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
 context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this, bcFilter);`

unregisterReceiver:

`context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(this);`

(Just at AppWidgetProvider!)