# Can a static arraylist of data objects cause memory leaks while the homescreen widget is running

Tags: java, android, arraylist, static, android-widget

In the following code i have a Class that contains a bunch of variables. I create a couple of instances of that class and save them to an arraylist. The arraylist is part of the same class, but marked static.
The same app has a homescreen app widget.
I worry that the static arraylist will stay in memory forever until the user deletes the app widget. Is this true?
Is the static arraylist a good idea or what could be an alternative?

```
public class Data {
    public static ArrayList<Data> listData = new ArrayList<Data>();
    String string;
    int integer;
    Data(String string, int integer){
        this.string = string;
        this.integer = integer;
    }
}

public class DataChanger {
    DataChanger(){
        Data.listData.add(new Data("string", 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> static arraylist will stay in memory forever until the user deletes the app widget

That is unlikely to occur, since the `AppWidgetProvider` is a convenience `BroadcastReceiver` class for Android widgets. If nothing else of your application is running, your process may be terminated between `onUpdate()` calls.

The official docs for `BroadcastReceiver` make it very clear that

> A `BroadcastReceiver` object is only valid for the duration of the call to `onReceive(Context, Intent)`. Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.
>
> This has important repercussions to what you can do in an `onReceive(Context, Intent)` implementation: anything that requires asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at that point the `BroadcastReceiver` is no longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation completes.
>
> In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from within a `BroadcastReceiver`. For the former, you should instead use the `NotificationManager` API. For the latter, you can use `Context.startService()` to send a command to the service.

References - [Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483435/11016588), [Reference 2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider), [Reference 3](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)